# Backslash in string changing output

Tags: string, haskell, recursion

I am currently trying to implement a method that counts the number of characters and digits in a string. However if I use a string that contains the '\' character I am getting strange results. I am guessing it's because the backslash character is an escape character.

Here is the method:

```
import Data.Char

countLettersAndDigits :: String -> Int
countLettersAndDigits [] = 0
countLettersAndDigits (x:xs) = if isDigit x == True || isLetter x == True 
                               then 1 + countLettersAndDigits xs 
                               else countLettersAndDigits xs
```

Here is a set of inputs with their respective results:

> "1234fd" -> 6 (Doesn't contain '\')
>
> "1234f\d" -> lexical error in string/character literal at character
>   'd'
>
> "1234\fd" -> 5
>
> "123\4fd" -> 5
>
> "12\34fd" -> 4
>
> "1\234fd" -> 4
>
> "\1234fd" -> 3

I find it strange that, for example, "1234\fd" and "123\4fd" both give 5 as a result.

Any help explaining why this maybe the case and also how to get around this problem? would be great!

Cheers.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that the string that I used above was just an example I was playing with. The actual string that is causing a problem is being generated by Quick Check. The string was "\178". So I require a way to be able to handle this case in my code when their is only one backslash and the string is being generated for me. Cheers.

Comment: The string `"\178"`, if you're seeing that as the output of `show` or `print` (basically, if it comes with quotes), is actually just one character, which is not printable.  See for example `map Data.Char.ord "\178"` which gives you the list of character codes.    If it doesn't come with quotes, then it's probably four characters.  It's a bit subtle if you're not used to escape codes.

Comment: You say you're having trouble with quickcheck. What's the quickcheck property you're using, maybe there's an invalid assumption somewhere in there?

Comment: I am new to Haskell and am using code wars to get up to speed. It was throwing the error when running my code so unfortunately can't give anymore details. Though I will look into escape codes and quick check more. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that `\` is Haskell's escape character. If you print out the generated strings, the answer may be more obvious:

```hs
main = mapM_ putStrLn [ "1234fd"
                      , "1234\fd"
                      , "123\4fd"
                      , "12\34fd"
                      , "1\234fd"
                      , "\1234fd"
                      ]
```

yields...

```txt
1234fd
1234d
123fd
12"fd
1êfd
Ӓfd
```

If you actually intended on including a backslash character in your string, you need to double it up: `"\\"` will result in a single `\` being printed.

You can [read up on escape sequences here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/characters-strings-and-escaping-rules.html).

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning how to actually include a backslash in case that's what he wants as the final effect.

Comment: @ChadGilbert Thanks for the answer. Definitely clear why it's generating these numbers. I have just added an edit to my question. The issue I am having is when the string is being generated by Quick Check.